# Как сделать чтобы программа реагировала на сочетание клавиш в русской раскладке

Tags: python, tkinter

как это сделать для *русской* раскладки `Control-Ч`?

```
event.widget.event_generate('<Control-X>')
```

Comment: `event.widget.event_generate("<<Cut>>")` будет работать независимо от раскладки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я делал так.

1. Сначала получал текущий язык раскладки по совету [отсюда](http://python.su/forum/topic/1946/):

   ```
   def is_ru_lang_keyboard(self):
       u = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("user32.dll")
       pf = getattr(u, "GetKeyboardLayout")
       return hex(pf(0)) == '0x4190419'
   ```
2. Потом определял метод `keys()` с учетом раскладки, т.к. без условия в случае английской раскладки метод давал дублирование строки при вставке:

   ```
   def keys(event):
       if self.is_ru_lang_keyboard():
           if event.keycode==86:
               event.widget.event_generate("<<Paste>>")
           elif event.keycode==67: 
               event.widget.event_generate("<<Copy>>")    
           elif event.keycode==88: 
               event.widget.event_generate("<<Cut>>")    
           elif event.keycode==65535: 
               event.widget.event_generate("<<Clear>>")
           elif event.keycode==65: 
               event.widget.event_generate("<<SelectAll>>")
   ```
3. Привязывал метод `keys()` к полю `Entry` к событию `"<Control-KeyPress>"`:

   ```
   self.my_entry.bind("<Control-KeyPress>", keys)
   ```

Comment: Стоит упомянуть, что такой способ определения раскладки будет работать только под Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать `Event.keycode`. Таким образом всё не будет зависеть от раскладки. Например, для вашего случая (<kbd>Ctrl-Ч</kbd> и <kbd>Crtl-X</kbd>)

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def keys(event):
    if event.keycode==88: # Клавиша с буквой Ч и с англ. буквой X
        print("Ура! Вы нажали Ctrl-Ч! (Или Ctrl-X)")
root.bind("<Control-KeyPress>",keys)
root.mainloop()
```

P.S.:
Сорри, про `Event.generate` я не знаю(((

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от `event`, который вы указали в `widget.bind()`. Если обрабатываете клавиши как в примере @Leo-Leontev:

```
def keys(event):
    if event.keycode == 88 and event.state == 4:
        print("Ctrl-X")
root.bind("<Control-KeyPress>", keys)
```

Добавил проверку `event.state == 4`, так как при Ctrl+Shift+X тоже будет вызов, в `event.state` хранятся модификаторы Ctrl (4), Shift (1), Alt (131072). Здесь можно указать просто `<KeyPress>`.

В этом случае нужно вызывать:

```
widget.event_generate('<KeyPress>', keycode=88, state=4)
```

Можно посмотреть на состояние объекта `event` после `event_generate()` (`print(event)`):

```
widget.event_generate('<Control-X>')
# <KeyPress event state=Shift|Control keysym=X keycode=88 ...>

widget.event_generate('<Control-x>')
# <KeyPress event state=Control keysym=x keycode=88 ...>
```

Answer (score -1):

Control-KeyPress-multiply - для большой Ч
Control-KeyPress-division - для маленькой ч