# Не работают сочетания клавиш ctr+v и ctr+c на русской раскладке в виджетах Enty и Text в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

На английской раскладке все работает корректно, но после переключения на русский сочетания ctr+v и ctr+c перестают работать. Пробовал забиндить на альткоды: `root.event_add('<<Paste>>', '<Control-igrave>')` и
`root.event_add("<<Copy>>", "<Control-ntilde>")`, как это описано [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/816947), но в моем случае это почему-то не работает. Пробовал другие варианты альткодов, такие как `Cyrillic_ve` - тоже не помогает.

Windows 7/64, Python 3.8.2

Comment: Посмотрите этот [пост](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588519/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5/1150156#1150156), там был дан ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то у них поломалось в последнем tkinter'е. Пока что рабочий вариант - через `KeyPress`

```py
def keypress(e):
    if e.keycode == 86 and e.keysym != 'v':
        cmd_paste()
    elif e.keycode == 67 and e.keysym != 'c':
        cmd_copy()
    elif e.keycode == 88 and e.keysym != 'x':
        cmd_cut()
root.bind("<Control-KeyPress>", keypress)
```